# buytoken function with erc20 interface

Tags: tokens, erc-20, address.transfer

I was following a [tutorial](http://www.dappuniversity.com/videos/xlHldvMNK8Q) that can buy erc20 tokens and I'm now stuck with transferring tokens to a buyer account which I need more clarification. So basically, a buyer account is trying to purchase some tokens. That's it.

For example, there's a contract that implements erc20 functions

```
contract DappToken {
    //...
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function DappToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

and there's another contract that takes `DappToken` contract as a parameter of its constructor.

```
contract DappTokenSale {
//...

    function DappTokenSale(DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens; 

        Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }
}
```

Here's my question, how does a buyer pass below requirement in `buyTokens` function?

`require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));`

My understanding is..

1. When the buyer tries to buy tokens, it will call `transfer` function in `DappToken` contract passing buyer's account address (`msg.sender`) and the number of tokens to purchase (`_numberOfTokens`).
2. `transfer` function in `DappToken` contract will check if the buyer has existing balance. `require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);`

But I don't understand why there's a check to see if a buyer has existing balance? What if it was the buyer's **first time** purchasing the tokens? then the buyer won't have existing tokens in `balanceOf` variable initially.

or is the `msg.sender` in `transfer` function a `DappTokenSale`'s contract address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain you a bit but first of all when a `contract` calls any function of another `contract` the `msg.sender` will be the address of the calling function. Now let me explain the follow. When a buyer wants to buy tokens he will call:

```
   function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens; 

        Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }
```

As indicating the buyer will specify that how much tokens he want to buy in `_numberOfTokens`. As the function is `payable` buyer need to send some ether along with the call which will indicate by `msg.value`, At the first there is check whether the ether send along the call is equal to the actual amount of the tokens. The second line will be confusion for you.

`this` is the address of the smart contract itself and `tokenContract.balanceOf(this)` is checking the balance of `DappTokenSale` contract account from the `DappToken` contract. In other words how much balance is of `DappTokenSale` inside the `DappToken` and it should be equal or more than the `_numberOfTokens` (line 2).

Lastly, third line is calling a `transfer` function of `DappToken` with `msg.sender` (buyer address) as `to` parameter, `_numberOfTokens` as `value` in the following function:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
```

Now, at first line `msg.sender` belongs to the `DappTokenSale` contract address and `_value` is `_numberOfTokens` and checking that the `DappTokenSale` has balance of more or equal than the `_numberOfTokens`. Then in the following lines just transferring the `_numberOfTokens` from `DappTokenSale` account to `buyer` account.

Note: Contract are also accounts and can be treated as address. Contract account can also have balance in another contract. There is no balance check on `buyer` address. In the above example `DappTokenSale` is acting as `sender` which sending tokens to buyer from `DappToken`.

Hope it will clear.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. So my assumption was right `or is the msg.sender in transfer function a DappTokenSale's contract address?`

Comment: when calling `transfer` function as this `tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens)`, this time `msg.sender` is buyer. inside the transfer function in `DappToken` as shown here `require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);` the `msg.sender` is `DappTokenSale`.